# Windows Form freezes while timer tick

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, backgroundworker, freeze

I have a problem, that my GUI is freezed while the timer ticks.

What should my Programm do: Read every 30 seconds my serialPort, save the data from the serialPort in a textfile and display the data on my windows Form.
Everything is working but, everytime the timer ticks my GUI freeze for 4-5 seconds.

Here my Code:(Visual C#)

```
-startButton(){...}
-RefreshComports(){...}
-stopButton(){...}



    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      myFile = new StreamWriter(path, true);
      serialPort1.NewLine = "\r";

      if (serialPort1.IsOpen == false)
      {
        serialPort1.Open();
      }
          data = serialPort1.ReadLine(); 

           myFile.WriteLine(data);

           if (data.Contains(':'))
           {
              String tmp[] = data.Split(':');
              textBox1.Text = tmp[1];
              textBox2.Text = tmo[2];
            }
            serialPort1.Close();
            myFile.Flush();
            myFile.Close();
}
```

I tried to do this with an backgroundworke instead of timer but then I can't update my textboxes.
Anyone could help me?

Comment: Use background worker and in ProgressChange event you  can update your textbox.

Comment: Is your data only sent every 30sec or do you want to throttle the recieved data by only reading one line every 30 sec? Why you dont use the [DataReceived](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx)-Event of the SerialPort class to start reading data? (Still needs Backgroundworker or another mechanism like Tasks to do the work on a Background Thread) I was just wondering why you need the Timer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Timer.Tick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick(v=vs.110).aspx) event handler is executed on UI thread. I.e. main thread of your application. This thread is responsible for drawing your application on screen. Running event handler on UI thread allows you to use any UI controls in this handler, but any long-running operation in Tick event handler will freeze your application, because UI will not be drawn at that time.

You should use [System.Threading.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) instead. It's callback is executed in background thread. Application will use main thread for drawing UI, and you will read data from port in other thread.

```
timer = new System.Threading.Timer(_ => CheckPort(), null, 0, 30000);
```

Your callback method:

```
    private void CheckPort()
    {
        serialPort1.NewLine = "\r";
        if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)
            serialPort1.Open();

        var data = serialPort1.ReadLine();

        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path, true))
            writer.WriteLine(data);

        if (data.Contains(':'))
        {
            var parts = data.Split(':');
            Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => DisplayData(parts[0], parts[1])));
        }

        serialPort1.Close();
    }

    private void DisplayData(string foo, string bar)
    {
        textBox1.Text = foo;
        textBox2.Text = bar;
    }
```

Note that you need to invoke method which uses UI controls. Because it's not allowed to use controls from thread other than main thread.

If you don't need to execute some operation periodically, then use [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) component to run operations in background thread.

Comment: You could also use [Systems.Timers.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx), that runs its Elapsed Event on another Thread than your UI Thread and then use [Control.Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx) to update your UI from the Non-UI-Thread. This way you don't need the Backgroundworker.

Comment: @BoeseB if you are not using ProgressChanged/RunWorkerCompleted event handlers of BackGroundWorker, then any call to UI controls will also require Invoke

Comment: wow, I hope downwoter don't have some big problems in his life. downvoting correct answers will not help him anyway

Comment: implemented with delegate. but form ui still freezing... interesting